# How do I see the BSSID of the Wifi AP I'm currently connected to in Windows?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, mac-address, ssid

In Windows, how can I find the BSSID of the Wifi Access Point I'm currently connected to?

Comment: Can downvoters comment why they downvoted?

Comment: LOL no, that would make too much sense.  Stack Overflow and co. said they wanted to make the Internet a better place - they do that by allowing anonymous downvoting thereby providing the OP with no constructive feedback with which to improve their answer whatsoever.  Oh well it does provide the OP with something - bad feelings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In a command prompt (you can launch one by using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type "cmd") type:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

and press enter.

Comment: Using `netsh wlan show interfaces | find "BSSID"` would be a little more straightforward.